# Dimension of Quot scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, dimension-theory-algebra

In the paper of Mukai & Sakai https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01171494, give a smooth projective curve $C$ and a vector bundle $E$ of rank $r$, they use the Grassmannian bundle $\mathbb{G}(E)$ to get a upper bound of dimension of the Quot scheme $Q_0$, where $Q_0$ parametrizes the locally free quotient of $E$ of rank $\rho$.

I am interesting to the case of a smooth projective surface, i.e., give a smooth projective surface $S$ and a vector bundle of rank $r$, what is the dimension of the Quot scheme $Q_0$, where $Q_0$ parametrizes the **torsion free** quotient of $E$ of rank $\rho$. But there is an obstruction that we can't get a morphism between $S\times Q_0$ and $\mathbb{G}(E)$. So I think whether there is another method to estimate dim $Q_0$?

More generally, is there a method to estimate the dimension of Quot scheme Quot$_{E/S/k}^{\Phi,H}$ with a fix Hilbert polynomial $\Phi$ and ample line bundle $H$?

Comment: @Harry-xiang - there are explicit formulas for the tangent space and the dimension of the tangent space of the hilbert and quot scheme. You should look up these formulas.

Comment: A problem is that the hilbert and quot schemes are not smooth and not irreducible in general, and it is an open (and difficult) problem to determine the irreducible components. Hence when calculating the dimensions of the tangent spaces you estimate the dimension of an irreducible component.